# Shallow copy of data structure with copy on write on Clickhouse

Tags: database, clickhouse

the problem is like that - there is a table with records like:

```
time, value
2020-04-01T10:00:00, 23
2020-04-01T10:00:01, 22
2020-04-01T10:00:02, 24
```

In Clickhouse database.

Then a script is called with some part of this data, for example with records ranging from `2020-05-01T10:00:00` to `20-06-01T10:00:00`.

This time-aware data could be changed over time, but the original data script was called with is need to be known. This could be solved with copying all the data the script was called with and storing it somewhere else, but this won't be memory efficient.

So, is there something, which would like 'reference mirror' it in something like 'Clickhouse view' without fully replicating it? Only the changed data in original table should be copied fully in an original form. So after this, when I reference that mirror view I get original data the script was called with. Is it possible in Clickhouse? How would you approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only the changed data in original table should be copied fully

There is no way to do it.
CH design does not allow on the fly to find out that rows with the same key already exists.

> How would you approach this?

I would store all history in one table and the last state in another.

Comment: Do you mean storing all  historic time-value data in one table and copying the data the script was called with to another table? Ideal scenario would be if I could somehow copy them on write, when they are being updated on that original data table, so I could copy minimal data amount, is it possible to hook in like that on the database level? Without primary keys ofc.

Comment: Yes you can do it using materialized views https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf
https://youtu.be/ckChUkC3Pns?list=PLO3lfQbpDVI-hyw4MyqxEk3rDHw95SzxJ&t=9371 https://youtu.be/j15dvPGzhyE https://youtu.be/THDk625DGsQ